# Not getting any records from ContentVersion in Salesforce SOQL query,

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I have an app that gets details of ContentVersion from ContentVersionIds. I'm attempting to retrieve specific details like `ContentDocumentId` and `Title` by executing the following SOQL query:

```
GET https://test.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentSize, FileType, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id='<Content_Version_ID>'
```

However, for some `ContentVersionIds`, this query doesn't yield any results. I've also made an attempt to use `QueryAll()` to determine whether the record has been deleted, but it consistently returns a 404 error with the message "The requested resource does not exist."

What could be the reasons for the API returning no records for some content version? It's worth noting that the access token I'm using to call the API possesses `refresh_token`, `api`, and `full` permissions.

Comment: Are you using the real domain (the one returned from successful login call) and that `test.my.salesforce.com` is just anonymisation for stackoverflow? What do you get when you run this query manually inside the org, say in Developer Console. Works for some but not all? Are they real files or for example Content Notes (they're stored as contentdocuments too just with special type). What if you add yourself a permission set with "Query All Files" ticked? Sharing on Files is trickier than you think and "whatever, sysadmin sees all" is not as automatic as with normal data.

Comment: @eyescream Yes I am using a real domain. I do not have access to the client's developer console. It works for some ContentVersions. I have no idea about Content Notes. Will check about it.

Comment: And by queryall you mean https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm? Because the way you wrote it with parentheses sounds like something from soap API docs. Ask the admin to run the query for you in Dev console / create the permission set with "query all files" and assign to your user?

Comment: @eyescream Thanks, I'll try your suggestions tomorrow. One observation is while the SOQL-based requests succeed with 200 response with no records returned, normal REST API calls (`GET https://test.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/<contentVersionId>`) returns 404 errors